# OKTA - Why authorization or endpoint endpoints not working?

Tags: authentication, authorization, token, endpoint, okta

I am trying to get the end points for my application via okta.

I am able to hit the below ones and see responses in both browser and postman.
https://xxx123.oktapreview.com/.well-known/openid-configuration?client_id=yyy

I got the below from the response.
"authorization_endpoint": "https://xxx123.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/authorize",
"token_endpoint": "https://xxx123.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/token",

But I hit the above URLs and getting
authorization endpoint - getting 400 error
token endpoint url - The endpoint does not support the provided HTTP method

I tried with authorization id, it doesnt work either.

Is it something firewall issue or some other thing which i am doing wrong.

Note: I installed the okta server in my machine, i am getting the same for that too. So I dont think it could be firewall issue.

Comment: Did you CORS enable your domain in Okta settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the required details with proper query parameters like client_id, response_mode, etc...
More details available in the below link as i exactly followed this.
https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-grant-type/authcode/main/#grant-type-flow